# Accidentally overwrote /usr/bin/python on Redhat

Tags: linux, centos, python, redhat-enterprise-linux

On Redhat, I had the bright idea of upgrading from Python 2.6.6 to 2.7.3 by running this command:

```
cp /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
```

This caused far-reaching problems throughout the whole system. The most notable of these is the fact that the yum installer depends on python.

I re-downloaded 2.6.6 from online and replaced it in /usr/bin/python. Now when I run `python -V` I'm running 2.6.6. However, when I run `python` and type `import yum`; the package can't be found.

Is it still installed somewhere on my system? How can I fix this? It's a colossal disaster.

I'm running Red Hat 4.4.7-16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use RPM to reinstall the Python 2.6 package. This should reset all the dependencies and rpm isn't dependent upon python.

First get a copy of the Python rpm from install media or official online Red Hat or CentOS repositories.

On my CentOS 6 host, the package is python-2.6.6-52.el6.x86_64. Your package may be different based upon platform and OS release.

`sudo rpm -Uvh --replacepkgs python-package.rpm`

As you have found, it's generally a bad idea to modify rpm managed executables. There are several discussions on the Internet on upgrading Python to 2.7 under RHEL/CentOS. You might want to start there.

Comment: Noting "4.4.7-16" isn't a Red Hat (or CentOS) version, but is likely the gcc version used in RHEL6/CentOS6.